# Woo-commerce is not redirecting to ccavenue gateway after filing billing information

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I am having an issue with my woocommerce portal where i am using ccavenue as a payment gateway. for integration of ccavenue I am using plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/ccavanue-woocommerce-payment-getway/) to setup the credentials received by the ccavenue portal like merchant id, access_code and merchant key.
When an user trying to purchase something, product is successfully added in the cart, and able to navigate to checkout page, but when user click on "Place order" button after filing all the required information such as billing details, the page is not redirecting to the gateway, it is remain on the same page (after reload). and i am unable to figure out what is causing the issue as it is not giving any error or console error.

```
1: wordpress is updated at its updated version
2: woocommerce and plugin is also updated.
```

please suggest how could I check the issue of this problem.

Comment: Contact the plugin author ? Its not updated for over 1 year and ccavenue could have some changes on theyr side too.

Comment: @MartinMirchev you are asking about ccavenue plugin or woocommerce? as i have updated all the plugins to their latest version. or will you recommend any alternative plugin to test it?

Comment: I am just mentioning that this plugin could be no longer supported. Contact the author here - https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/ccavanue-woocommerce-payment-getway/

Comment: after changing the ccavenue plugin, it working like Charm!